# Prevent pycharm & python from prepending `sys.path` with the directory of the ran file

Tags: python, pycharm, sys.path

I cannot determine why pycharm & python are prepending `sys.path` with the directory of the ran file.

Suppose my project layout, called `project`, with dependency called `dependency` is structured like this:

```
projects/
  project/
    app/
      main.py
  dependency/
    lib/
      libfile.py
```

Pycharm settings:

- "Working directory" is set to `projects/project`
- "add content roots to PYTHONPATH" is **checked**, and both `project` and `dependency` are imported as content roots in the project structure.
- "add source roots to PYTHONPATH" is **not checked** and I've not marked any folders as source roots.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
list(map(print, sys.path))
```

Running `file.py` with pycharm with these settings results in a path that starts with `projects/project/app` even though I'm setting the "working directory" to `projects/project`

pycharm **main.py** output:

```
projects/project/app
projects/project
projects/dependency
(...site packages...)
```

and if run from a terminal in `/projects`, `PYTHONPATH=/projects/project:/projects/dependency python app/main.py` yields **main.py** output:

```
projects/project/app
projects/project
projects/dependency
(...site packages...)
```

so still not what I want but it matches pycharm.

**QUESTION**: How do I prevent python/pycharm from adding `projects/project/app` to the start of `sys.path`?

Comment: The output you say you're getting from `PYTHONPATH=/projects/project:/projects/dependency python app/main.py` shouldn't happen - running Python like that should place the `app` directory at the start of `sys.path`. (It should also show `/projects/project` and `/projects/dependency` in the output, with leading slashes.)

Comment: You can see in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdarg-script) that running a Python file by file path places that file's directory at the start of `sys.path`: "If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory containing that file is added to the start of sys.path". Unless you've got a weird alias for `python` that adds the [`-P` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P) to turn that off or something, the script's directory should show up.

Comment: @user2357112 Well shit, I just reran it and I don't know what I was seeing before but you're right. In any case, how do I get it to stop adding `/projects/project/app` to the start of the `sys.path`?